# How to call a class method from another class instance

Tags: c#

I'm new to `C#`, I'm in doubt about how to make this work:

```
namespace Core {
    public class A{
        private reandonly string _var;
        public A(string var){
            _var=var
        }
        public GetValue() => return _var;
    }
}

using System;
namespace Core.Resources {
    public static class B{
        public static void DoSomething(){
            Console.Writeline($"{A.GetValue()}");
        }
    }
}

public class C{
    static void Main(string args[]){
        A a = new A("name");
        a.Resources.B.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

`A` is in main folder, `B` is in `Main/Resources` folder, together they make a classlib, `Program.cs` is using this lib. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Change `a.Resources.B.DoSomething();` for `Core.Resources.B.DoSomething();`

Comment: In your code, class A does not have a property called Resources. also, your only constructor for the A class contains a string, while your c# tries to instantiate it using a parameter-less constructor. with all these mistakes, It's kinda hard to figure out what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If you write `a.Resources` you are basically trying to retrieve the member `Resources` of the class `A`, which is obviously not defined. Since `B` is a static class defined in the `Core.Resources` namespace, all you have to do is to change your code as follows:

```
public class C
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        A a = new A("A");
        Core.Resources.B.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

or, alternatively, if you don't want to reference the namespace every time:

```
using Core.Resources;

public class C
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        A a = new A("A");
        B.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Note that if yuu explicitly define a public constructor for `A` that accepts one or more arguments, the default parameterless constructor is no more available... hence you have to pass a string to the `A` constructor if you don't want to see an error in your console. Alternatively, you have to rewrite your `A` class so that it implements a default parameterless compiler, for example:

```
public class A
{
    private reandonly String _var;

    public A() : this(String.Empty) { }

    public A(String var)
    {
        _var = var;
    }
}
```

**EDIT AS PER OP COMMENTS AND QUESTION CHANGES**

```
public class A
{
    private reandonly String _var;

    public String Var
    {
        get { return _var; }
    }

    public A(String var)
    {
        _var = var;
    }
}

public static class B
{
    public static void DoSomething(String text)
    {
        Console.Writeline(text);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        A a = new A("name");
        B.DoSomething(a.Var);
    }
}
```

Comment: the parameterless constructor was a mistake, the need of that it's B class needs the _var value used in 'a' construction

Comment: You can't do that like this. The class `A` is not static... so `$"{A.GetValue()}"` this is wrong. You have to pass the value of the instance to the `B.DoSomething()` method as argument... hence the method must be changed too. You seem pretty much confused about the difference between static classes and instances. See my edit.